# Measuring time Interval Since Now

Tags: iphone, sdk, xcode4, nsdate, nstimeinterval

anyone know or can provide some example code relating to "timeIntervalSinceNow" method...

I need something like... time2(when app eneters foreground) - time1(when app enters background) = time3(the difference in times)... this is so i can use this number(pref in seconds) to calculate the time i have lost while the app has been in background !!

I am having trying trying to create the date objects, receive the object and display/use in a label....

Answer (score 4):

Actually, to answer your original question, myles, you can use `timeIntervalSinceNow`. 
In the statement below, `inputDate` has been initialized as an `NSDate` and set to some date (you could just try `[NSDate *inputDate = [NSDate date];` to set the date at the current date and time.

```
NSTimeInterval timeToAlert =[inputDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

The next line is a way to put that `NSTimeInterval` into a string.

```
NSMutableString *timeinterval = [NSMutableString string];
[timeinterval appendFormat:@"%f",timeToAlert];
```

Finally, the app delegate class is typically where code can be written to handle coming in and out of background. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

`timeIntervalSinceNow` tells you the offset of an `NSDate` from the current time. You want `timeIntervalSinceDate:`:

```
NSDate *appEnteredForeground = ...;
NSDate *appEnteredBackground = ...;

NSTimeInterval difference = [appEnteredBackground timeIntervalSinceDate: appEnteredForeground];
```

Comment: it keeps saying "Unused variable 'difference'" i dont know how to get the value from difference and put it into a label. btw should i be doing this in the delegate's ?? many thanks for the help dude !!

Comment: It sounds like you might need to take a step back and learn the basics of C and Objective-C before diving headlong into UI design. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the difference between two dates with the `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method:

```
//When app enters background:
self.backgroundDate = [NSDate date]; //this should be a property 
//...
//When the app comes back to the foreground:
NSTimeInterval timeSpentInBackground = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.backgroundDate];
```

`NSTimeInterval` is simply a typedef for `double`, it's measured in seconds. `[NSDate date]` instantiates an `NSDate` object with the current date and time.

Comment: how do i create a property for backgroundDate ??

Comment: [The Objective-C Programming Language – Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17)