# iphone - difference between time(app hiding) and time(app appearing)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, xcode4

how do i get  the date from appEnterBackground and take away from appEnterForeground, then show the difference in a label.
This is my code so far..

```
**.h**
    NSTimeInterval appEnteredBackground;
    NSTimeInterval appEnteredForeground;
    NSTimeInterval difference;  

**.m**

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    appEnteredBackground = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    appEnteredForeground = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    difference = appEnteredForeground - appEnteredBackground;

    NSLog(@"Duration is %@",[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: difference]);
    NSLog(@"Duration is %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", difference]);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", difference];   **//ERROR HERE (variable not used)**

    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

Any help would be fantastic

Comment: @onnoweb: **//ERROR HERE (variable not used)** i want to get the value of 'difference' into a label or string so i can use it in a calculation...

Comment: possible duplicate of [timeIntervalSinceNow help !!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144966/timeintervalsincenow-help)

Comment: You already asked this *exact* question. Asking again won't help you.

Comment: @Jonathan: just getting lost and needed some help.

Comment: You should read the documentation for `NSDate`. It looks like you're trying things at random. The documentation tells you what methods like `+dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you do not have errors here. You are correctly calculating the time difference, then you build a string with its "description" but do not use it.

To see if it all works correctly try this before the end of the method:

```
NSLog(@"Computed time was: %@", time);
```

You should care about that `time` variable, since you are not actively using it.

Answer (score 0):

To measure this type of event (or difference of events), you need something with resolution of less than a second.  There is a "c" interface to get the machine time, which is the hardware free running "ticks" inside the processor.

You can get **really** fine timing (milliseconds, microseconds if you believe them) using this StopWatch class.

**StopWatch.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface StopWatch : NSObject 
{
    uint64_t _start;
    uint64_t _stop;
    uint64_t _elapsed;
}

-(void) Start;
-(void) Stop;
-(void) StopWithContext:(NSString*) context;
-(double) seconds;
-(NSString*) description;
+(StopWatch*) stopWatch;
-(StopWatch*) init;
@end
```

**StopWatch.m**

```
#import "StopWatch.h"
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

@implementation StopWatch

-(void) Start
{
    _stop = 0;
    _elapsed = 0;
    _start = mach_absolute_time();
}
-(void) Stop
{
    _stop = mach_absolute_time();   
    if(_stop > _start)
    {
        _elapsed = _stop - _start;
    }
    else 
    {
        _elapsed = 0;
    }
    _start = mach_absolute_time();
}

-(void) StopWithContext:(NSString*) context
{
    _stop = mach_absolute_time();   
    if(_stop > _start)
    {
        _elapsed = _stop - _start;
    }
    else 
    {
        _elapsed = 0;
    }
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@] Stopped at %f",context,[self seconds]]);

    _start = mach_absolute_time();
}


-(double) seconds
{
    if(_elapsed > 0)
    {
        uint64_t elapsedTimeNano = 0;

        mach_timebase_info_data_t timeBaseInfo;
        mach_timebase_info(&timeBaseInfo);
        elapsedTimeNano = _elapsed * timeBaseInfo.numer / timeBaseInfo.denom;
        double elapsedSeconds = elapsedTimeNano * 1.0E-9;
        return elapsedSeconds;
    }
    return 0.0;
}
-(NSString*) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f secs.",[self seconds]];
}
+(StopWatch*) stopWatch
{
    StopWatch* obj = [[[StopWatch alloc] init] autorelease];
    return obj;
}
-(StopWatch*) init
{
    [super   init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

The class has a static `stopWatch` method that returns an autoreleased object.

Once you call `start`, use the `seconds` method to get the elapsed time.  Call `start` again to restart it.  Or `stop` to stop it.  You can still read the time (call `seconds`) anytime after calling `stop`.

**Example In A Function**  (Timing call of execution)

```
-(void)SomeFunc
{
   StopWatch* stopWatch = [StopWatch stopWatch];
   [stopWatch Start];

   ... do stuff

   [stopWatch StopWithContext:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Created %d Records",[records count]]];
}
```